# How to Commit For Each File Recursively with Git in Bash?

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to push a lot of big binary files to GitHub and it always fails because of big commit sizes.

So I decided to write a bash script which adds and commits each file recursively under given directory, so I can push them one by one.

This is what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

for FILE in ${PROJECT_DIR}/*
do
    echo ${FILE}
    git add ${FILE}
    git commit -m "initial commit ${FILE}" 
done
```

But when file names have spaces or unicode characters, it fails.

I am looking for a robust script for this purpose.

Comment: `I am trying to push a lot of big binary files to GitHub` ... why are you trying to do this?  Git does not handle binary files well, and large binary files are bad in particular.  Maybe you should square away first why you think you need to do this.

Comment: Use commas in `git add "$FILE"`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to version control them.

Comment: @Saibot: You could add multiple files at once. If you could give sample names of the file, you could add all of them in one shot to `git add`

Comment: @Inian I know I can add multiple files, but then I get a giant stage, then giant commit, then push crashes.

Comment: @kip I couldn't understand how to use commas.

Comment: @Saibot: In that case what you are missing is just double-quotes around `$FILE`, do `"$FILE"`

Comment: @Saibot sorry, double-quotes is double-quotes, my bad english !

Comment: Oh, gonna try it now, thanks.

Comment: No, it still gives an error when encounters whitespace.

Comment: I didn't get it. How will it help? @TomFenech

Comment: Sorry, the `-a` doesn't help if the files haven't been committed before. I was just suggesting that you added all the files together and committed them in a single commit. You could use `git add .` and `git commit -m "Initial commit"` to do that. I don't see what you gain by having separate commits for each file.

Comment: @TomFenech I want to push small commits, to be able to push each commit successfully. When I push a giant commit, it fails.

Comment: @Inian Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @Saibot: did not hear back from you if it worked! :) ( I did not downvote by the way!)

Comment: @Inian It worked, I was going to accept your answer. It was late yesterday, I had to leave office, so I couldn't let you know that it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with lack of appropriate quotes in your `git add` command. Not enclosing it within double-quotes leaves the variable susceptible to Word-Splitting by the shell i.e. splitting of a string into individual words by the delimiter (default being the whitespace)

```
shopt -s globstar        
for fileToCommit in ${PROJECT_DIR}/**/*; do
    test -f "$fileToCommit" || continue 
    printf "%s\n" "${fileToCommit}"
    git add "${fileToCommit}"
    git commit -m "initial commit ${fileToCommit}" 
done
```

Comment: @Saibot: That is more a safety check, to gracefully handle when no files are found for the loop to work on in the `PROJECT_DIR` folder. If not used, the loop will throw an error if no files are found for the loop

Comment: Thanks, but this is not processing recursively for every file in subdirectories (except .git of course)

Comment: Other option would be to use `nullglob` to prevent the loop from running when no files match.

Comment: @Saibot: Add a `globstar` option now, enable it and run the loop. Now you get recursion across all sub directories